# xmlhttp not supporting in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

xmlhttp not supporting in IE ,actually i had created one facebook app by which users can play game with each other randomly,problem is when i want to test it, i login in my facebook userid in firefox,and i login with my brother facebook id in chrome but they are connecting to each other,do you think that it beacuse of same ip address we are not connecting OR it is not creating xmlhttprequest object for IE AND CHROME....

function GetXmlHttpObject()
                {
                var xmlHttp = null;

```
            try
                {
                // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            catch (e)
                {
                //Internet Explorer
                try
                    {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                catch (e)
                    {

                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                    }
                }

            return xmlHttp;
            }
```

Comment: Which version of IE is this? Is ActiveX enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You *need* to post the code you are trying to run, we can't help you based on this vague description of your problem.

One thing I will say is check for trailing commas at the end of object lists, this is the #1 thing that will break javascript in IE. For example this will break IE but not Firefox/Chrome because of the comma at the end:

```
variable = ['one', 'two', 'three', ]
```

Comment: i had put code now in my question, pls HElp, Thanks in advance